# Vegas Pro 13 - Shaking Image - Including Preview

Tags: vegas-pro

Can I shake a transparent .png image in 3D?

[image: Preview]
<sub>(source: [ggpht.com](https://yt3.ggpht.com/-x_OUuSU9y5g/U9AL1oZo4uI/AAAAAAAAAds/IXXz10WDaeY/w1060-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd/abc.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In a nutshell:

1. place an image on the timeline (set Alpha Channel in media properties if needed)
2. click 'Track Motion' button in the track header
3. select '3D Source Alpha' compositing mode
4. use keyframes to create animation